# Change Lable (Name of countries) according to Attribute values ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I'm creating a world map using ArcMap. I want to style the label in such a way that their name should be displayed as the attribute value. For example if I'm using population data then the China's font should be largest then other

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered here: [How to create label with variable size in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72286/how-to-create-label-with-variable-size-in-arcmap). In short, use a label expression to set the text size equal to your population values.